# Direct I/O access via O_DIRECT and std::fstream

Tags: c++, linux, file, file-io, fstream

I've got a C++ application in which I frequently write a file on an SSD. To bypass the page cache of the kernel, I intentionally give hint to the `open()` system call via `O_DIRECT` attribute as below.

```
const int fileDesc = open(fileName.c_str(), O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_DIRECT);
```

Normally, I access the file using the `fstream` in C++. However, I couldn't find a way to implement the direct I/O behavior using the `fstream`. There are [options](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) that define the opening mode, but none of them manages the I/O handling strategy.

I want to use the `fstream` as it provides various different operators when writing to the file.

Is there a solution for that?

Comment: [boost::iostreams](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/file_descriptor.html#file_descriptor) might help